# Read file using comma separated values in c

Tags: c, file-io

I have a text file that goes in the format string,string,number

occupation,residence,salary

How could I read this in since it is comma separated? I have the following code

```
int t;
char occupation[20];
char residence[20];
int salary;

fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");

while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fp) != NULL) {
    t = sscanf(buffer,"%20[^,],%20[^,],%d",occupation,residence,&salary);
    if (t == 3)
    {
        addToFront(linkedList,salary,occupation,residence);
    }
}
```

I know my addToFront isn't the issue because if I call it with something like:

```
addToFront(linkedList,50000,"plumber","miami");
```

it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The code should work, but be aware that if you read 20 chars into a 20-char declared space, you have no space for the trailing 0. So declare your variables one longer than what you expect (`char occupation[21];`)

It is unclear how your buffer is declared - is it at all?

Actually, you don't need a buffer at all, you can use `fscanf` which is identical to `sscanf` except that it takes a file pointer instead of a buffer.

Comment: I just had char buffer[50000]